# Custom shape for TextureView, CameraViewFinder or PreviewView

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl

i would like to customize the outline. The `ViewOutlineProvider` with `setPath()` and `setConvexPath()` but unfortunately without success. My aim is to let the view appear in a rectangle shape with a barrel shape and rounded corners. That means that the applied mask need to create alpha pixels to let the mentioned views background shine through.

After several attempts it seems that this have to be done with an GL stencil buffer implementation. For performance reasons i don't want to do a canvas copy with a color filter.

- FrameLayout which hols a vector mask
- Canvas, PorterDuff
- ViewOutlineProvider